# C# bitmap - Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, graphics, bitmap

I am making a basic windowed game in c# and I am unable to create a basic bitmap for the screen. I have a panel over the screen and I want to be able to draw to it, so I am using the following code:

```
 public partial class GameWIndow : Form
{
    public GameWIndow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }





    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap buffer;
        buffer = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(buffer))
            {
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.PaleGoldenrod), 10, 10, 100, 100);
            }
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.BackgroundImage = buffer;
            }));
        });
    }
```

when this runs it gives me the error "Parameter is not valid" for the line

```
buffer = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
```

Width and Height are 900 and 700 respectivly, and both integers.

If the problem is that I am doing this entirely wrong, what would be a better way to acomplish this.

--------Edit-------

I have looked at your comments and it seems that what I have done above is very terrible so I tried a different approach, and I am not sure if that is much better.

```
    private Game game;
    private Thread renderThread;
    private Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    public GameWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Starts game
        game = new Game();

        //Starts rendering
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        renderThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(draw));
        renderThread.Start();
    }

    //Runs when screen is asked to refresh
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Sends graphics to game class where it draws game
        game.draw(e.Graphics);

    }

    private void draw()
    {
        stopwatch.Start();

        while (true)
        {

            //If 1/60th of a sec has passed
            if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 1000D / 60D)
            {

                stopwatch.Restart();
                Invalidate();

            }
        }

    }
```

The code above doesn't run correctly, I am not quite sure why, and if someone could help with that, I would appreciate that. However my major question isn't how to fix it, but if this is even a effective or "correct" way to draw.

Comment: The problem is likely that you are doing this entirely wrong.  I don't know specifically why you're getting that error, but modifying the GUI from any other thread than the one it was created on is prohibited.  (On a closer read, that's definitely not why you're getting this error, but the rule still applies.)

Comment: What are you trying to do? This looks a little suspicious. The `PaintEventArgs` already contain an instance of `Graphics` that you should be drawing on.

Comment: If you enable the double-buffered style for that control, you can just write the `Paint` event-handling code in the most straightforward way.

Comment: @vcsjones: Drawing to an in-memory buffer during Paint is not unusual, although the last step should be blitting the results to `e.Graphics` , not setting the `BackgroundImage` property.

Comment: what I want to have is a seperate thread to handle my drawings and another one to do my game logic, is there a way I could do that, or is that a bad idea?

Comment: @AnthonyRobertson: If you want that split, better to do the drawing on the UI thread and the state updates on the worker thread.  Everything is just simpler that way.

Comment: The panel shouldn't be the one setting the form's background image.  If you are trying to just paint the panel, then paint the panel.  And use the panel's dimensions:  `buffer = new Bitmap(panel1.ClientSize.Width, panel1.ClientSize.Height);`

Comment: @BenVoigt ill try that, thanks

Comment: Well, you are using the Paint event. But everything else is wrong indeed ;-)

Comment: Your updated code is much worse.  Don't run a while-loop in the paint event.  Also, you aren't drawing anything.  To get this to work, I would drop the threads and just use a basic timer to invalidate your drawing.

Comment: That is not the correct way to draw and you didn't follow any of my suggestions. Please get a book like [Programming Windows Forms](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-microsoft-windows/9780735685116/). WinForms is too large to learn through trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

As @TaW suggests, there are many problems. I assume this is the Paint event handler of a WinForms application? That is important information you should have told us.

The Paint event handler is called by the OS every time anything in your form content needs redrawing. `PaintEventArgs` supplies you with the `ClipRectangle` you must draw into and the `Graphics` context you must draw with. You should only draw to that in your handler; you must not perform any other processing, start threads, or perform any I/O. If you need to load images or perform I/O you must do that outside your handler, save the result to a form property, invalidate the rectangle you want to draw to, then use the saved property to draw in your Paint handler. It should look something like this:

```
private void Panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(_buffer, _position);
}
```

What's `_buffer`? An `Image` you fill outside the handler. `_position`? A location you update outside your handler.

Do not allocate buffers, `Brush`es, or images inside your Paint handler; create them outside the handler and reuse them. If you need to update your control with the result of a long process or network connection, create a `Task` or `BackgroundWorker` outside your handler and have the completion routine save the result and invalidate your control. Use the saved result in your handler. If you need to perform some kind of animation, precreate all the animation frames, use a timer to invalidate your display, and draw the correct frame in your handler.

WinForm graphics is a huge topic, you need to get a book or follow a tutorial.